# how to enable ICU support with boost::regex?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, unicode, icu

We are working with boost::regex library to have unicode support. I want to form a regex for validating unicode characters so I'm trying this with boost library.

I am facing an issue for boost library with ICU support so please suggest me how to proceed with the boost with ICU support.

tried this - on b2 install

[image]

expecting this - boost documentation

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post images of errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: This may help: https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/3rdpartypublic/boost/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html  Basically it says if you get has_icu_builds = no then boost build couldn't find icu on your computer.